# What is wrong with the code here, intended at finding ceasers cipher?

Tags: c, char, return

I am trying to pass char pointer type as the return type of the function, but not getting anything as the output. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
char * decrypt(char* pt)
{
    char*  result=malloc(20);
    while(*pt)
    {
    *result=*pt+3;//incrementing by 3 alphbets and copying in reslult
    pt++;
    result++;
    }
    *result='\0';
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char plaintext[20];
    scanf("%s",plaintext);//getting input

    char *ct= decrypt(plaintext); //passing to function

    printf("\nCiphertext %s",ct);//printing reslut

}
```

Comment: Add a '\n' at the end of your printf.  Also, you're leaking memory.

Comment: Don't forget to `free` if you `malloc`.

Comment: `result` will be pointing to end of the string.

Comment: Check the result of malloc(), it could be NULL

Answer (score 2):

`result` will be pointing to `\0`, after the loop.

Just add temporary pointer to point to beginning of the string and return.

```
char * decrypt(char* pt)
    {
        char*  result=malloc(20);
        char *start = result;

        while(*pt)
        {
           *result=*pt+3;//incrementing by 3 alphbets and copying in reslult
           pt++;
           result++;
        }
        *result='\0';

        return start;
    }
```